# EF PostgeSQL migrations script: CREATE Table if it doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

In my project I have this migration:

```
public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Studios",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                Company = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Studios", x => x.Id);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Studios");
    }
}
```

I am using PostgeSQL (`pgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`).

I generate SQL file with `Script-Migration` or `dotnet ef migrations script`, which generates this SQL file:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "__EFMigrationsHistory" 
(
    "MigrationId" character varying(150) NOT NULL,
    "ProductVersion" character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK___EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY ("MigrationId")
);

START TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE "Studios" 
(
    "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "Company" text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Studios" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
VALUES ('20210202135422_InitialCreate', '7.0.13');

COMMIT;
```

This SQL I can run, but only once. Because for the second run it will fail with

> ERROR:  relation "Studios" already exists

My question, why does it generate such SQL? Why it doesn't it generate `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Studios"` and how to fix it?

Comment: From  Documentation: [Idempotent SQL scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#idempotent-sql-scripts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Svytoslav was right. I missed, that there is flag `--idempotent`, that generates migration if we don't know current state of db.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#idempotent-sql-scripts